# Update with limit 1 in codeigniter use active record

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying to update a single record with the active record of codeigniter and it still fails.

```
$data = array('status' => 1);

$this->db->where('field1', $info);
$this->db->update('example', $data);
$this->db->limit(1);
```

When i run updates all fields of the database.
By making a $ this->db->last_query() does not show me the limit

What is the error

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Move the limit before the update which should be always called last:

```
$this->db->limit(1);
$this->db->update('example', $data);
```

Comment: when writing the post I forgot to add the db $this->limit (1)

Comment: Success is added before and after the limit, it worked thanks