# CodeIgniter UPDATE and LIMIT

Tags: codeigniter

I know this question has been posted already before [Update with limit 1 in codeigniter use active record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086767/update-with-limit-1-in-codeigniter-use-active-record)

But it seems combining UPDATE and LIMIT using Active Record doesnt work on my side. It will still update all record based on the WHERE clause. I'm currently using CodeIgniter 3.0.6. Is this a bug from CodeIgniter already?

[screenshot of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahez0.png)

Comment: show your `update` method from `sendidb` model

Comment: sendidb is not a model, its the same as $this->db, i just assigned sendidb as the database object

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly add limit in update query. I get an alternative way. Firstly you get one row by where query and then run the update query with using fetching row unique key like unique auto increment id.

```
$singleInfo = $this->db->get_where($tbl, array('user_id'=>1));
$this->db->update($tbl,array('username'=>'FredSmith'),array('user_id'=>$singleInfo->id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I fired up CI 3.0.6 and used this as a demonstration, as we cannot see your setup.

```
public function db_update_test_with_limit(){
    $tbl = 'users';

    // Use Chaining - Works
    $this->db
        ->where('user_id',1)
        ->limit(1)
        ->update($tbl,array('username'=>'FredSmith'));
    echo $this->db->last_query();

    // Use discrete calls -  Works
    $this->db->where('user_id',1);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $this->db->update($tbl,array('username'=>'FredSmith'));
    echo '<br>';
    echo $this->db->last_query();
}
```

And the results for both are...

```
UPDATE `users` SET `username` = 'FredSmith' WHERE `user_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
UPDATE `users` SET `username` = 'FredSmith' WHERE `user_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

So if you are doing the same thing and getting different results, then something funky is going on.

If you use this as a test and massage it to suit your situation, does it work or not?

Comment: hmm really doesnt work on my side. Now im confused whats going on. I havent changed any code in CodeIgntier or even override anything from CodeIgniter

Comment: I also tried this: $this->sendidb->query("UPDATE SchoolStatusChanged SET FromDate='".$data['CommencementDate']."' WHERE SchoolId='1' LIMIT 1").  Though, when i last_query it shows the LIMIT part but it doesnt update any record at all

Comment: Sorry to state the obvious but did you change $data['CommencementDate'] to a different value to see if it did change. If you are running this as straight SQL and it's not working, we are missing something blindingly obvious here.

Comment: Just one other question... If you are running that straight plain ole SQL statement on your DB and you are not seeing it changing... Are you looking at the same DB you think you are pointing at in your config? That's never happened before :)

Comment: sorry for the late reply. i just confirmed it that i changed the value of CommencementDate and it was pointing to the right database. really confusing and disappointing already since the LIMIT clause will solve a lot of logic in my system

Comment: is there any workaround for this? can u recomment a different query without using the LIMIT?

Comment: Well the workaround is to get it working... So if you have access to something like phpmyadmin or similar and you perform that SQL directly on the database, that HAS to work! Can you try that?

Comment: Ill try running that query in the database. i'm  currently using MySQL

Comment: but if there's a workaround like updating only the record with the highest or lowest Id number, that would be great

Comment: Well you can use ORDER BY along with LIMIT to alter the highest or lowest id. Have you got a sample dump of your database you can provide?

Comment: i tried running this query in MySQL and it throws an error:
update SchoolStatusChanged set FromDate='1970-01-10' where SchoolId='1' LIMIT 1

ERROR:
Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'.

Comment: does this mean MySQL doesnt support it?

Comment: i just decided to run two queries, this already taking up so much time. anyway thanks a lot for the response. really appreciate it

Comment: MySQL does support it. I can run that command with success till the end of time and it works each time... So no idea what you've got going on at your end. Even though mine works with the quoted 1 in SchoolID ='1' can you try it without the quotes so its SchoolID = 1

Comment: without quotes SchoolId=1 still works, but if adding LIMIT will cause an error

Comment: What is your version of MySQL?

Comment: SQL Server 2014, im not sure if thats the MySQL version no

Comment: What about ORDER BY clause? Where does it go?