# Remove rows by given size in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

i want to remove rows from table with dynamic number
for example

```
remove 45 rows where have status = 'Free'
```

45 is a parameter received from user.

```
/*$inputs['inputExamCount'] is 45*/
for ($i = 0; $i < $inputs['inputExamCount']; $i++) {
  $this->db->delete('agency_person_exams', array('status','Free'))->limit(1);
}
```

is this best way to remove table rows?

Comment: Why not put the number into the limit? then you only run one SQL rather than loop over it n times

Comment: If `limit(1)` works with your database engine (I don't know how CodeIgniter implements it), what prevents you from doing `limit(45)`?

Comment: yes. it not worked because i place limit after delete. now i set limit before delete and it worked. thank all of you!

Comment: maybe consider also to an order by, like to remove the older record

Comment: yeah . but in this case it's a discount code table and I want to delete some discount codes

Comment: Related: [Update with limit 1 in codeigniter use active record](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12086773/2943403)

Comment: yes . limit works. some times I think a lot :)